# Can another wallet pay for, Sign and Send transaction signature of another Keypair

Tags: transaction, keypair, signer

if i create a custom instruction that requires a Keypair can another Keypair or client wallet sign or pay the transaction fees of said instruction please also explain how such things work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. you can however, there are some caveats:

- If the keypair is used as the `payer` it will need enough funds for gas fees + account rent exemption.

You can then use the `partialSign` method to partially sign the instruction with the `Keypair` & then additionally sign with your own key & send.

Alternatively the first `Keypair` could sign & then just use another keypair as the `payer` & that would also work